# Magento Admin suddenly slowed down

Tags: performance, magento, backend

We have Magento EE 1.14. Admin was working fine till last two days its speed dropped dramatically. Frontend is not affected. Also no changes in code or server configuration. here is my attempt to fix the problem but nothing worked:

- Log cleaning is properly configured
- removed two unused extensions. but no improvement
- tried to disable non-critical extensions to see if speed will improve but also not luck.
- I can NOT use REDIS cache at this time. but configured new server which is using REDIS cache and move to it next month.
- sometimes backend will gain speed for few minutes
- I enabled profilers the source of the delay is mage ( screenshot attached ).
  [image]

**here are my question:**

- **Is there anyway to know the exact reason for Mage delay ?**
- **do I have other test i can use to identify the cause of delay ?**

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be delay on external resources connection. Do you have new relic or similar software? Check there for slow connections. If You don't have NR, profile admin by blackfire.io. Magento profiler is really unhelpful :)

Comment: I found the problem it was one of the extension that no longer supported. i had to disable it and

Answer (score 0):

Follow below steps:

**Delete unused extensions**

It is best to remove unused extensions rather than just disabling them. If you disable an extension, it will still exist in the database. It would not only increase the size of your database (DB) but it also adds to the reading time for DB. So, keep your approach clear: If you don’t need it, DELETE it.

**Keep your store clean by deleting unused and outdated products**

One should keep in mind that a clean store is a fast store. We can operationalize the front-end faster by caching and displaying only a limited set of products even if we have more than 10,000 items in the back-end, but we cannot escape their wrath. If the number of products keeps on increasing at the backend, it may get slower, so it is best to remove unused products. Repeat this activity in every few months to keep the store fast.

**Reindexing**

One of the basic reasons why website administrators experience slow performance while saving a product is because of reindexing. Whenever you save a product, the Magento backend starts to reindex, and since you have a lot of products, it will take some time to complete. This causes unnecessary delays.

**Clear the Cache**

Cache is very important as far as any web application is concerned so that a web server does not have to process the same request again and again.